# HTTPS request in python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, https, command

I can't find documentation on this. Is it possible to run an https request in python 2.7?

I tried this code for 3.2, but these modules don't exist in 2.7.

```
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.urlopen('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/redluck2013/profile?        fields=transaction_sold_count&api_key=1pmmjgt3j4nz5ollhzz2hvib')
print(r.read())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 2.7:

```
import urllib2

r = urllib2.urlopen('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/redluck2013/profile?fields=transaction_sold_count&api_key=1pmmjgt3j4nz5ollhzz2hvib')

print(r.read())
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 1):

Package `urllib.request` was added in python 3, it does not exist in python 2.7.

In python 2.7, use `urllib.urlopen`

This has nothing to do with https.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding https, please note:

```
Warning HTTPS requests do not do any verification of the server’s certificate.
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

If you do require https verification, python requests is a very useful library

```
import requests
url = https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/redluck2013/profile?fields=transaction_sold_count&api_key=1pmmjgt3j4nz5ollhzz2hvib
r = requests.get(url, verify=True)
content = r.text
```

For the verification, just make sure to pass True to the verify argument.

More here:

- http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/
- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Comment: the code is not valid Python. Also, you don't need the explicit `verify=True` e.g., `requests.get('https://docs.python-requests.org')` fails because the hostname does not match.